# Why is SublimeText 3 making my leading spaces black?

Tags: sublimetext3

SublimeText is putting an ugly black color on all of my leading spaces and tabs. This started happening a few days ago. I don't think I changed anything.

Can someone help me to make my SublimeText look beautiful again?

[image]

Comment: Is a fresh install not an option for you?

Answer (score 3):

The problem was the Highlight Whitespaces plugin. When I removed that, then the ugly black spaces went away. Strangely, I've had that plugin installed for months and it never caused a problem until now.